# Обработка изображений с помощью Python

Tags: python, изображения

вопрос немного нестандартный. Нужна помощь в том, в какую сторону искать информацию.
Хочу написать скрипт на Python, который будет обрабатывать изображение тем фильтром, которым я укажу.
Фильтр был заранее сгенерирован в другом любом редакторе.

Т.е Мне понравился фильтр в приложении Инстаграм или VSCO(для прошаренных). Я хочу забрать его к себе и обрабатывать изображения с помощью него автоматически или пакетом.
В теории, знаю, что при создании масок в Инстаграме, интерфейс фб предлагает наложить на специальную картинку свой фильтр, который инста потом считает и уникализирует для всех изображений.
Как называется такой метод? Если не питон, то где еще подобное можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой метод обработки изображений называется 3D LUT, подробнее можно почитать тут – https://habr.com/ru/post/491542/